# 7DOF inverse kinematics spherical wrist

Tags: inverse-kinematics, manipulator, matlab

Is it possible to apply kinematic decoupling for a 7 DOF 7R manipulator with spherical wrist?  If it is possible, can anyone suggest a reference on how to apply this approach with a redundant manipulator with spherical wrist, or explain why it is not possible?

I'm working with Robotic Toolbox (matlab) and the numeric algorithm can find the inverse kinematics solution without a problem if I don't specify the orientation.  And I was thinking about solving the problem a second time considering the spherical wrist.  Will this approach work?

Answer (score 4):

I believe kinematic decoupling used to be the standard procedure for 6 DOF arms.  (6R with spherical wrist).  Where you would solve the 3 DOF position IK first, then 3 DOF orientation IK.

If you have a spherical wrist, I don't think there is any reason why you *can't* decouple your problem like this.  However, I assume you now have a 4 DOF arm to reach a 3D point.  You have 1 redundancy, so your IK will probably give you a number of solutions.  So you should do your orientation IK on top of all these...

That being said, i don't believe anyone does it like this anymore.  I know at least my kinematics library of choice ([OpenRave](http://openrave.org/)) can solve 7 DOF IK problems.  It does so by discretizing the extra DOF(s).